# Painting app with huge canvas

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on yet another drawing app with canvas that is many times bigger than screen.
I need some advice/direction on how to that.

Basically what i want is to scroll around this big canvas, drawing only in visible region.
I was thinking of two approaches:

1. Have 64x64 (or whatever) "tiles" to draw on, and then on scroll just load new tiles.
2. Record all user strokes (points) and on scroll calculate which are in specified region, and draw them, using only screen-size canvas.

If this matters, i'm using cocos2d for prototype.

Comment: Maybe a couple of CATiledLayers stuck in their own scrollView would be perfect then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget the 2000x200 limitation, I have an open source project that draws 18000 x 18000 NASA images.

I suggest you break this task into two parts. First, scrolling. As was suggested by CodaFi, when you scroll you will provide CATiledLayers. Each of those will be a CGImageRef that you create - a sub image of your really huge canvas. You can then easily support zooming in and out.

The second part is interacting with the user to draw or otherwise effect the canvas. When the user stops scrolling, you then create an opaque UIView subclass, which you add as a subview to your main view, overlaying the view hosting the CATiledLayers. At the moment you need to show this view, you populate it with the proper information so it can draw that portion of your larger canvas properly (say a circle at this point of such and such a color, etc).

You would do your drawing using the drawRect: method of this overlay view. So as the user takes action that changes the view, you do a "setDisplayInRect:" as needed to force iOS to call your drawRect:.

When the user decides to scroll, you need to update your large canvas model with whatever changes the user has made, then remove the opaque overlay, and let the CATiledLayers draw the proper portions of the large image. This transition is probably the most tricky part of the process to avoid visual glitches.

Supposing you have a large array of object definitions used for your canvas. When you need to create a CGImageRef for a tile, you scan through it looking for overlap between the object's frame and the tile's frame, and only then draw those items that are required for that tile.

Answer (score 2):

Many mobile devices don't support textures over 2048x2048.  So I would recommend:

- make your big surface out of large 2048x2048 tiles
- draw only the visible part of the currently visible tile to the screen
- you will need to draw up to 4 tiles per frame, in case the user has scrolled to a corner of four tiles, but make sure you don't draw anything extra if there is only one visible tile.

This is probably the most efficient way.  64x64 tiles are really too small, and will be inefficient since there will be a large repeated overhead for the "draw tile" calls.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tiling example in Apples [ScrollViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) Doesn't have anything to do with the drawing part but it might give you some ideas about how to manage the tile part of things.

Comment: Yeah thanks, i saw the videos on that, idea is pretty good. Though i was thinking about using opengl for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CATiledLayer.
See WWDC2010 session 104

But for cocos2d, it might not work.